# How to turn a greater strict function into an aggregate

Tags: postgresql

I have been looking for a max function setting null to the max value and found the following on (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/r2y162867791004201002x50843917y3d1f1293db7451e0@mail.gmail.com) :

```
create or replace function greatest_strict(variadic anyarray)
returns anyelement as $$
  select null from unnest($1) g(v) where v is null
  union all
  select max(v) from unnest($1) g(v)
  limit 1
$$ language sql;
```

The problem is that this function is not an aggregation function usable for group by. How can I change that? Such that I can use the following query:

```
SELECT greatest_strict(performed_on) as start_date
from task
group by contract_id;
```

Comment: You have to use `CREATE AGGREGATE` to create an aggregate function. You'll have to write a transition function for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created this before: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_strict_min_and_max

I call it strict_max, not strict_greatest, because "max" is already an aggregate so that seems like a better name.

This has the advantage (over the other answer) of not storing all the values in memory while it is aggregating over them, so that it can work on very large data sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own aggregation functions.

```
create aggregate agg_greatest_strict(anyelement) ( 
    sfunc     = create_array,
    stype     = anyarray,
    finalfunc = greatest_strict,
    initcond  = '{}'
);
```

`sfunc` is a function which will be executed for every row and returns an intermediate result.

`finalfunc` will be executed afterwards with the result of the last `sfunc` execution.

In your case you could create the arrays for every row (your `sfunc`):

```
create or replace function create_array(anyarray, anyelement)
returns anyarray as $$
  SELECT 
      $1 || $2
$$ language sql;
```

This simply aggregates the row values into one array. (first parameter is the result of the previous execution; if it is the first one, `initcond` value will be taken instead)

Afterwards you can take your function as `finalfunc`:

```
create or replace function greatest_strict(anyarray)
returns anyelement as $$
  select null from unnest($1) g(v) where v is null
  union all
  select max(v) from unnest($1) g(v)
  limit 1
$$ language sql;
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b9b7cbe065cd48acac57750c05eae768)

---

**Edit**: Former solutions without any `finalfunc` function using the `greatest()` function on every row:

- [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4bb92afa35074295c4ef3d5eb691db7a) (one `sfunc` for `anyelement`)
- [demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=504b815a5bedb469bedeca4c97ab2038) (overloaded `sfunc` for `text` and `numeric` type because of some problem with special chars and ASCII-order)